# Can IMAP be used to get original Gmail HTML

Tags: python, html, regex, django, email

I am working on a project in python/django where for each individual gmail conversation, I want to grab the most recent gmail reply. Using IMAP I'm able to grab the body of the conversations and separate out the text.I had planned to use a regex to get the most recent conversation, but unless I'm missing something I can't find a consistent delimiter that separates the most recent reply.

Looking back in gmail itself I see that there is an HTML class that may hold the most recent
reply. If I could get the original gmail html I might be able to parse it.

```
<div class="msg">
<div>
<div dir="ltr">
    message goes here ...  
    <br>
```

does IMAP have the ability to grab the original email message HTML seen in the browser? If not is there any other approach I could use?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do something like grouping the messages into conversations, and then picking out the latest message in a given conversation? Or do you want to separate out the different quoting levels in a single message? Regardless, Gmail doesn't have anything to work with other than the content of the message either, so getting the Gmail HTML won't help, I think.

Comment: I want to pick out the latest message in a given conversation